# Can't open build.sh [Ubuntu 18.04]

Tags: docker, sh, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install vimbasrc folowing the manual provided by AlliedVision [here](https://github.com/alliedvision/gst-vimbasrc/blob/master/README.md). When I run the following command after building Docker image

`$ docker run --rm -it --volume /media/hamza/new/volume1/project/gst-vimbasrc-master:/gst-vimbasrc --volume /media/hamza/new/volume1/project/opt/Vimba_5_1:/vimba gst-vimbasrc:18.04`

I keep getting this

```
sh: 0: Can't open build.sh
```

I've tried reinstalling Docker and looking for missing dependencies.
The build.sh file looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -o verbose
# ============================================================================
cmake -S . -B build -DVIMBA_HOME=$VIMBA_HOME
# ============================================================================
cmake --build build
# ============================================================================
```

I am completely stuck.
Does anyone know the way out?

If I run ./build.sh it runs but because it needs path to vimba directory it gives

```
fatal error: VimbaC/Include/VmbCommonTypes.h: No such file or directory
 #include <VimbaC/Include/VmbCommonTypes.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, the build.sh should be in your "/media/hamza/new/volume1/project/gst-vimbasrc-master".
Because the documentation states:
*"Building the plugin with this image is simply a matter of mounting the source code directory and the desired Vimba installation directory into the image at appropriate paths, and letting it run the provided build.sh script."*

Thus, it is probably missing from here. In this place, you should mount the source code provided.

When you run the image, it will look into the gst-vimbasrc project : this is the purpose of this line in the Dockerfile :

```
# mount the checked out repository into this volume
VOLUME ["/gst-vimbasrc"]
WORKDIR /gst-vimbasrc
```

Comment: That was my guess too but it is present and as i have stated in the original post, is running too but running it directly does not provide the desired results.

Comment: You can basically do a "RUN ls" just after the workdir : this way you will be sure of that